# How to specify negative range for slider control?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, sdi

I am developing a MFC based SDI VC++ application. In my application I need to specify negative range value for my Slider Control. The minimum range for the Slider is -40 and maximum range is 255. I tried it using SetRange function. But it is not working. How can I set this range in the slider?Please Help..

My code for the Slider is as follows:
Slider is declared as

```
CSliderCtrl m_ctrlECTSlider;
```

OnInitialUpdate function contains

```
m_ctrlECTSlider.SetRangeMin(-40);
int iValMin = m_ctrlECTSlider.GetRangeMin();
m_ctrlECTSlider.SetRangeMax(255);
int iValMax = m_ctrlECTSlider.GetRangeMax();

m_ctrlECTSlider.SetPos(0);
SetDlgItemInt( IDC_ECT_VALUE, m_ctrlECTSlider.GetPos(), FALSE);
SetDlgItemInt( IDC_MIN_ECT, iValMin, FALSE);
SetDlgItemInt( IDC_MAX_ECT, iValMax, FALSE);
```

OnBnClickedSet function contains

```
int nMin = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_MIN_ECT, 0, FALSE);
int nMax = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_MAX_ECT, 0, FALSE);

m_ctrlECTSlider.SetRange(nMin, nMax);
m_ctrlECTSlider.SetPos(nMin);

int pos = m_ctrlECTSlider.GetPos();
SetDlgItemInt(IDC_ECT_VALUE, m_ctrlECTSlider.GetPos(), FALSE);      
m_ctrlECTSlider.RedrawWindow();
```

Here the problem is the value returned during debugg is all correct. But when it comes to UI on running the min value is 429496 and not -40 in the edit box..Why is it so..I am developing SDI application using CFormView class..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your minimum value is '-40'which is signed integer and You are treating as unsigned integer as last parameter of 'SetDlgItemInt' and 'GetDlgItemInt'  method is 'FALSE'.
That's why you are getting wrong value in place of '-40'.
Use following code for correct behavior.

//For setting value

SetDlgItemInt( IDC_ECT_VALUE, m_ctrlECTSlider.GetPos(), TRUE);

SetDlgItemInt( IDC_MIN_ECT, iValMin, TRUE);

SetDlgItemInt( IDC_MAX_ECT, iValMax, TRUE);

// For getting value use as follows

int nMin = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_MIN_ECT, 0, TRUE);

int nMax = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_MAX_ECT, 0, TRUE);

You can use this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7t43w0s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Call `void SetRangeMin(int nMin, BOOL bRedraw = FALSE);`  as :

```
m_Slider.SetRangeMin(0);
```

And call `void SetRangeMax(int nMax, BOOL bRedraw = FALSE);` as :

```
m_Slider.SetRangeMax(50);
```

Also before calling `GetPos()` verify that the slider is in the range by calling the `VerifyPos()`

This is good tutorial on MFC Sliders - [Windows Controls: Sliders (Track Bars)](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/slider.htm).

Comment: Range accepts values < 0, unless you have tied it up to something else. Maybe posting the relevant part of code might help us to sort out the problem.

Comment: These pieces of code would have been better of with the question. Also with the declaration of Slider.

Comment: Will you please update the question with code for declaration, usage, etc of slide?

Comment: Is your value of `nMin` and `nMax` in `OnBnClickedSet` function correct?